# Any idea why my query only works on first but on second isset nothings happen

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

```
if (isset($_POST['submitid'])) {
    $itemid = $_POST['itemID'];

    $cartno = mysqli_query($connection , "SELECT * FROM users");
    while ($cartnorow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cartno)) {
        $existingcartno = $cartnorow['cartno'];
        $existingtotal = $cartnorow['total'];
    }   
    $updatecartno = $existingcartno + 1;    
    $updateprice = $itemlistprice+$existingcartno;  
    mysqli_query($connection ,
      "UPDATE users SET cartno = '$updatecartno' WHERE id=1");
}
```

When I remove `WHERE id = 1` it works fine.

I seriously need to update specific id thats why I need that `WHERE id = 1`.

Comment: Are you sure the users with id = 1 exists? Are you sure the column name is "id" and not "id_user" or something like this?

Comment: yup its "id" not "id_user"

Comment: Are you sure you want to work with all users?  Your select doesn't include any criteria to match a user and then you want to update another user with the value you fetch +1?  Sorry - this doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: THANK YOUUUUUUU YOU GAVE IDEA :)))))))